# Redirect a directory as input to a script and output to a file

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, pipe

I want to use a directory name as a parameter for a pre-made script. Then the output goes into a newly made file in the home directory. It involves pipe/redirection. How do I do that?

```
read dir
$dir > script > outputfile
```

Comment: ok I figured out the syntax something like: script<$dir >|outputfile but it doesn't seem to accept directory as a parameter unless I entered it wrong. and how can I choose home directory as the location for outputfile?

Comment: you have to use `script < $dir > ~/outputFile`. Here `~` is the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the directory name as-is in your script, pass it as a parameter:

```
script $dir > outputfile
```

You can't redirect a directory to a script, what do you expect to see as the input? The name? The names of the directory entries? The contents of the directory entries? etc.

I'm assuming as you're writing scripts, you know how to process a parameter. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Show the script. It's not a homework assignment, is it?